# Implement fine uploader javascripts in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, valums-file-uploader, fine-uploader

Finally after so much testing and so on, i made it works. But i`m confused which files do i need and why im getting an error.

i have

/Scripts/fineupload/

- handler.base.js
- handler.form.js
- handler.xhr.js
- uploader.basic.js
- util.js

My script bundle is

```
 BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new AmazonS3ScriptBundle("~/bundles/gzip/fineuploader")
                .Include("~/Scripts/fineuploader/handler.base.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/fineuploader/handler.form.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/fineuploader/handler.xhr.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/fineuploader/uploader.basic.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/fineuploader/util.js")                   
                );
```

When i try to load my page im getting an error

My Page

```
 <div id="fine-uploader" class="btn btn-primary"><div>Select Files</div></div>
....
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/gzip/fineuploader")
...
```

Fine uploader javascript is rendered as single file ex. somemd5.js

I try to init my uploader on document ready as

```
  uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
        multiple: false,
        autoUpload: false,
        button: $("#fubUploadButton")[0],
        request: {
            endpoint: "http://localhost:64247/upload/uploadfile"
        },
        callbacks: {
            onError: errorHandler
        }
    });
```

Im getting to much errors, but ill start with the last one..
[image: Last Error]

If i just includeuploader.basic.js, im getting error like 
[image: jsut bacis js]

Which files do i need? In zip file from github, there are 10 javascript files (some empty).
Its strange why on test page from zip, everything works but when i implement in my proejct it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely why a zip file with combined/minified & version-stamped js, along with version-stamped css & resource files is available.  Click on the download link either on the [homepage](http://fineuploader.com) or at the top of the readme in the master branch.